# Ansible updates itself to new version what brings problems

Tags: ansible

Need your help with something stranges. 
Our Ansible versions seem to update itself.

Is this normal, or am I in the wrong with this.

The problem has kept us busy for days now. 
Does anybody have some ideas about why this could be?

Is there a way to prevent from this.

Thank you in advance.

Kind Regards,

Wesley

We have been looking through the ansible code for auto-update commands but didn't find anything. Also, have been looking to the auto yum commands.

Ansible is current 2.8.4 the latest
Also we are running on Centos 7

Comment: Please provide more information: On which OS is this happening, is Ansible running in docker, ...

Comment: Ansible is running on centos 7, I have updated the system

Answer (score 0):

Ansible upstream developer here. Ansible does not have any self auto update code mechanism. We rely on either PyPI or Linux distribution repositories for software release and update. Something or someone is doing updates on your system.

Do you possibly have yum auto updates enabled on your CentOS machine via `yum-cron`?

https://linuxize.com/post/configure-automatic-updates-with-yum-cron-on-centos-7/